# Error al separar una columna en dos

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe como este:

```
 Chenopodium_album:


                        POS         Nut
                        096_(C)     G_1
                        122_(G)     T_2
                        123_(T)     C_4
                        126_(A)     A_1
                        809_(G)     A_6
                        810_(A)     C_5
                        828_(C)     T_2
```

La estructura sería algo así:

```
structure(c("096_(C)", "122_(G)", "123_(T)", "126_(A)", "809_(G)", 
            "810_(A)", "828_(C)", "G_1", "T_2", "C_4", "A_1", "A_6", "C_5", 
            "T_2"), .Dim = c(7L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("POS", "Nut"
            ))) -> Chenopodium_album
```

Y quiero separar la columna dos en sus dos valores separados por el guión bajo.

Para ello uso esta función:

```
  Chenopodium_album_x <- data.frame(sapply(strsplit(Chenopodium_album$Nut, "_"), "[[", 1))
```

y obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error in Chenopodium_album$Nut : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

La clase de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
             class(Chenopodium_album)
             [1] "matrix"

             class(Chenopodium_album[,1])
             [1] "character"

             class(Chenopodium_album[,2])
             [1] "character"
```

Por lo que no se donde está el error.
¿Cómo podría corregir este error? 
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta corta: no puedes usar el operador `$` en matrices, respuesta algo más larga: el operador `$` esta disponible únicamente para objetos recursivos es decir no atómicos. Cualquier objeto basado en una lista por ejemplo, permite el uso del `$`, los `data.frame` también, ya que son casos especiales de listas. Una matriz es un objeto atómico, por lo cual, no corre el operador `$`.  Para verificar si un objeto es atómico, podrías hacer: `is.atomic(Chenopodium_album)` o al revés, si es recursivo: `is.recursive(Chenopodium_album)`.

Para separar cada columna, de una forma parecida a lo que has intentado, podrías hacer esto:

```
new <- cbind(
          sapply(strsplit(Chenopodium_album[,1], "_"), "[[", 1),
          sapply(strsplit(Chenopodium_album[,1], "_"), "[[", 2),
          sapply(strsplit(Chenopodium_album[,2], "_"), "[[", 1),
          sapply(strsplit(Chenopodium_album[,2], "_"), "[[", 2)
)
```

En vez de usar `$` accedemos a cada columna por índice, es decir `Chenopodium_album[,1]` y  `Chenopodium_album[,2]`, o también, una forma un poco más compacta sería:

```
new <- cbind(
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(Chenopodium_album[, 1],'_')),
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(Chenopodium_album[, 2],'_'))
)
```

Y por último, si usaras `tidyverse` podrías hacer algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

Chenopodium_album %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  separate(POS, c("POS1", "POS2"), sep='_') %>% 
  separate(Nut, c("Nut1", "Nut2"), sep='_')
```

Comment: Las tres alternativas funcionan, muchisimas gracias Patricio