# Error al dividir una columna delimitada por un símbolo

Tags: r

Estoy intentando dividir una columna que está delimitada por un .
Una columna como esta:

```
   prueba:
                     Prueba
                     NC_001440.1
                     NC_002034.1
                     NC_001440.1
                     NC_002034.1                         
                     NC_002034.1
```

Para ello he ejecutado la siguiente función:

```
          prueba %>% 
            as.data.frame() %>% 
            separate(prueba, c("prueba1", "prueba2"), sep='.')
```

y me da el siguiente error:

```
 Warning message:
 Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 13824674 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].
```

Y me da un resultado en blanco.

Hace unos meses pregunté en este foro por métodos para separar columnas delimintadas por un signo ([Error al separar una columna en dos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275847/error-al-separar-una-columna-en-dos)) de las tres opciones para mi supuesto solo se ejecuta la primera (aunque me de un objeto en blanco).

Cuando checkeo de que tipo son mis datos obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
     class(prueba$prueba)
     [1] "character"
```

¿Cuál es mi fallo?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisamos la [documentación](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) de `separate()` en particular lo que dice con respecto al parámetro `sep`:

> If character, is interpreted as a regular expression. The default
>   value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of
>   non-alphanumeric values.

Es decir, se espera que `sep` sea un patrón de expresiones regulares y particularmente el punto (dot) tiene un significado muy puntual, hace referencia a "cualquier caracter", por lo que si quieres el punto deberás "escapearlo"

```
prueba %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>% 
   separate(prueba, c("prueba1", "prueba2"), sep='\\.')
```

Comment: Funciona Patricio! Muchas gracias por la ayuda