# Tratando de dividir los nombres de filas

Tags: imagen, dataframe, rstudio, split

Soy nuevo en la comunidad y tengo la siguiente consulta en lenguaje R (estoy trabajando en RStudio), por favor:

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente dataframe:

```
               Sample_01
BGN_BGN        1.0000000  
RPS4Y1_BGN    -0.2367307  
COMP_BGN       0.2664066 
COL2A1_BGN     0.2746505  
LOC653219_BGN -0.2651348 
XAGE1_BGN     -0.2604609
```

Se puede ver que los nombres de los genes están unidos por '_' y lo que quiero es separar los nombres de estos en columnas individuales para que al final quede cada columna separada por cada gen, por ejemplo:

columna 1(gen1) - columna 2(gen2) - columna 3(Sample_1)

Espero haberme explicado correctamente

Muchas gracias de antemano por las sugerencias

Comment: Por cierto, cual sería la forma de encontrar las 3 partes que mencionas? Por que solo veo dos partes no tres.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que quiero separar los nombres de los genes, estos estan unidos por el simbolo '_' entonces en el primer caso quedaría BGN(1ra columna) BGN(2da columna) y 1.000(3ra columna)

Comment: Ok, te entiendo. Hay varias formas, no voy a hacer una respuesta por que ya hay varias preguntas en el Sitio que hablan de esto. Fijate si entendés por ejemplo esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275847/error-al-separar-una-columna-en-dos sino cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré

Comment: Estimado Patricio, he intentado hacer lo que el tutorial que me enviaste sugería, lo he realizado con el siguiente codigo:       > cormat %>%
+   as.data.frame() %>%
+   separate(cormat, c('Gen1', 'Gen2'), sep = ' ')
Error:
! Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
✖ Subscript `var` has the wrong type `double[,53]`.
ℹ It must be numeric or character.          Me ha entregado error, no sé a qué se debe, podrías orientarme con algun otro ejemplo, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada voy a convertir tu ejemplo en un `data.frame`, entiendo por lo que muestras que el nombre de lo genes no esta en una columna sino en un `rowname`.

```
read.table(text="               Sample_01
BGN_BGN        1.0000000  
RPS4Y1_BGN    -0.2367307  
COMP_BGN       0.2664066 
COL2A1_BGN     0.2746505  
LOC653219_BGN -0.2651348 
XAGE1_BGN     -0.2604609",  header=TRUE) -> df
```

Usando `tidyverse` y el verbo `separate()` podemos fácilmente resolver tu consulta, siempre que transformemos antes el `rowname` en una verdadera columna:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column('genes') %>% 
  separate(genes, into=c('gen1', 'gen2'), sep='_')

       gen1 gen2  Sample_01
1       BGN  BGN  1.0000000
2    RPS4Y1  BGN -0.2367307
3      COMP  BGN  0.2664066
4    COL2A1  BGN  0.2746505
5 LOC653219  BGN -0.2651348
6     XAGE1  BGN -0.2604609
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, lo repetiré para todo el data.frame.. Saludos